# set and set delayed in dynamic programming

Tags: programming

The first one is running

```
   Module[{f},
     f[1] = f[2] = 1;
     f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
     f[5]
     ]
```

But the second one never ends its loop.

```
Module[{f},
 f[1] = f[2] = 1;
 f[n_] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
 f[5]]
```

Why does this loop never end?

Comment: In the second example the RHS of the definition for `f[n_]` evaluates immediately and tries to evaluate 'f[n-1]` and `f[n-2]` with **symbolic** arguments. This sets off an endless recursion until the recursion limit.

Comment: @BobHanlon  Do you mean `f[n_] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]` will never try to use `f[1] = f[2] = 1`?

Comment: It is evaluating the RHS with the symbol `n` and will never have an integer argument.

Comment: If you force the argument of `f[n_]` in the second version to be of kind Integer as in `f[n_Integer] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]` then that version works to. @BobHanlon's observation is correct.

Comment: @user7515079 thank you for your answer.